# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im new in node js, when im trying to sent data to database from react, on my node js got error 'can't set headers after they are sent. i've been searching for same like this problem, but it doesnt help me to solve this problem

i've tried using writeHead on the post(the second one) 
but it doesn't help, is it bcs i sent the same image? i only got problem with sending the same image

```
app.post('/list', function(req, res){
    const {namaCabor, descCabor, imgCabor } = req.body;
    connectDb.collection('listCabangOlahraga').insertOne(req.body, function(err, res){
        console.log(res.insertedCount +'data inserted');
    });
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.post('/add', function(req, res){
    const {categoryName, categoryDesc, categoryImage, namaCabor, descCabor, imgCabor } = req.body;
    connectDb.collection('listCategoryCabangOlahraga').insertOne(req.body, function(err, res){
        console.log(res.insertedCount +'data inserted'); 
        if(err) throw err;
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick analysis : Your code involves writing to MongoDB collection. It has an async callback. I guess the res.write() / res.send() should be included inside the callback?

If not, they get executed even before the DB operation is complete and we won't know if it succeeded or not.

```
app.post('/list', function(req, res){
    const {namaCabor, descCabor, imgCabor } = req.body;
    connectDb.collection('listCabangOlahraga').insertOne(req.body, function(err, res){
        console.log(res.insertedCount +'data inserted');
        // <----- Handle the error here and print response accordingly.
    });
    res.send(req.body); //Move this inside callback. Return error response if err encountered.
});

app.post('/add', function(req, res){
    const {categoryName, categoryDesc, categoryImage, namaCabor, descCabor, imgCabor } = req.body;
    connectDb.collection('listCategoryCabangOlahraga').insertOne(req.body, function(err, res){
        console.log(res.insertedCount +'data inserted'); 
        if(err) throw err;
        // <----- Handle the error here and print response accordingly.
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}); // Move this inside callback.
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //Write response from the callback.
});
```

Basically the error appears because res.write() / res.send() is called before setting the header

Also it's a good idea to have the res object renamed in either of the places (maybe the `res` (result) object in the MongoDB write callback can be renamed to avoid potential confusions with the `res`(response) object of the express route)

Comment: on post one its works fine, but on the other post which means('/add'), when i type data from my front and input type file(in my case its image) always got the error can't set headers, but if i just type text in there its works fine, why is that possible?

Comment: and also i just changed that code as u can say, but still got the problem when i upload the image file

Comment: can you share the output of the console ? when it errors and when it doesnt ?

Comment: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\backend-cabor\node_modules\express\lib\response
.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\backend-cabor\node_modules\express\lib\response.j
s:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\backend-cabor\node_modules\express\lib\response.j
s:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\backend-cabor\node_modules\express\lib\response.j
s:158:21)
    at D:\backend-cabor\app.js:20:21

Comment: thats the error but if the data works just sent it with '1 data inserted'

Comment: but i already figured it out, in my react/front need the multiparth/form-data in my content-type :'multipart/form-data' and also on my form, if  i do that i got no errors in my console

Comment: its because i upload file image that's give me an error

Answer (score 0):

I guest that you have an error handler. In the /add route, it throws an error and your error handler will catch it. So you tried to set response header in both /add handler and error handler. The second handler will throw the error *'can't set headers after they are sent* because response was already sent in the first handler(may be error handler or /add handler)

Answer (score 0):

This error occur whenever node try to send http response after it has been sent,
e.g

```
{if(true){
res.send({})
}
res.send({
// this will throw that error because the pool is already close because the first res.send was executed.
});
}
```

However, in you case there is no such scenario visible in the code you posted,
but in in server.js, a method executed might have sent the response to the frontend and the pool is closed before the route controller finish processing causing the res.send or res.end in your code to throw the error.

So try to check other portion of your code base to debug this error.